# how to set child div width 80% to parent div

Tags: css, html

i want to set child div width to be 80% of parent div. how to do

```
<div id='container'>

        <div id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="padding:3px; vertical-align: middle; white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
            <button id="BtnPreviousMonth">Previous Month</button>
            <button id="BtnNextMonth">Next Month</button>
        </div>

        <div id='subcontainer'>

        <div id="mycal" style="position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

when i set mycal width and height in %. it has no effect. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `width:80%` , you can set width in percentage(`%`) , The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="child">
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
   position:relative;
   width:500px;
   height:100px;
}
#child{
   width:80%;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/U8NJd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You must have to provide with to parent div then after you can give width in % to child div.

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet `mycal` is absolutely positioned. That means that its width and height in `%` will be relative to the nearest non-static positioned parent (position: relative, absolute, fixed) or to the body in case there is no such. If you want to give `mycal` `80%` width of `subcontainer` you can make

```
#subcontainer {
    position:relative;
}
```

but, since `subcontainer` does not have a defined height and it's child is absolutely positioned (and therefore doesn't affect parent's height) - `subcontainer`'s height is 0. Therefore `20%` of `0` is `0`. To solve this issue, you can either specify height of `subcontainer` or populate it with static positioned content.

Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/iYOQAKiS/1/edit

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="padding:3px; vertical-align: middle; white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
        <button id="BtnPreviousMonth">Previous Month</button>
        <button id="BtnNextMonth">Next Month</button>
    </div>

    <div id="subcontainer" style="position:relative;">Some static content
      <div id="mycal" style="position:absolute;width:80%;height:20%"> 
        MyCal content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to set `width` 80% to the `child` `mycal`, set `width` to its `parent` `subcontainer`

```
#subcontainer{
   width:1000px;
   heigth:1000px
}

#mycal{
   width:80%;
   height:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set a percentage `width` and `height`, it has an effect. 
I guess, the problem in your case is, that it is just not visible, set some `background-color` to see it

```
#mycal {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: plum;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNb6F/)

Although, this might not be what you want. Since you've set [`position: absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos), the containing box is not `subcontainer`, but the body element.